# git checkout master on two machines gives different results

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I'm trying to move our (very small) company from svn to git and so am experimenting with workflows.  Our primary goal is for both developers (I said small company) to be able to work on their branches on their pc and at night on their mac, without interfering with each other until the branch is stable…at which point they merge the branch back into master.

Each developer has a local repo and we have a bare "origin" repo on an EC2 machine.

So far vanilla, right?

So I created a test branch, and did all manner of changes, commits, pulls, pushes, etc. on it from several machines.  All good so far.

Then I did:   "git checkout master; git merge testBranch"  on one machine to merge the changes in testBranch to main.

Then on my other machine I said   "git checkout master"…and did not see the changes from testBranch!  I also tried "git pull origin master" but still see the pre-testBranch-merge version of some files.

At this point I can say "git checkout master" on the two machines and end up with different versions of files, which to my understand should be impossible.  I've seen no errors on either machine while doing these commands.

Any help understanding how this could be would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Unless you pull, checking out master will check out the most recently pulled local master.

Comment: I don't see where you pushed the changes from that checkout/merge back to the ec2 repo.

Answer (score 1):

Git is a **distributed** version control system. `git checkout` does **not** check anything out from a central server. You are confusing SVN's notion of checkout with git's checkout command.